# My function 'sleep' blocks the others processes

Tags: c, process, sleep

I have to create a program that displays characters several times with a delay between each character. You'll understand better thanks to the example I'm going to give you. Each display is done by a process, so the program is multi-processes and the displays are done in parallel.

The data are saved into a file which contains the following lines:

```
a 4 2
b 2 1
```

So, for **example**, the char 'a' is displayed 4 times with a delay of 2 seconds ; in parallel, 'b' is displayed 2 times with a delay of 1 second.

The code I wrote compiles and can be executed without any error. But, with this file, it only displays 'bb'. If I delete 'sleep'-call, it displays correctly all the 'a' and 'b' (but without any delay).

Thus, the 'sleep' function seems to allow only one process and stops the others. Do you know why ? I thought it would block only the calling-process.

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pid_t pid;

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        perror("Open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // <!-- The following vars are used for the reading of the file -->
    char current_char = 0;

    char char_to_print; // ie. : the first file's column

    char buffer_number_of_prints[592] = {0}; // ie. : the snd file's column
    int i1 = 0; // Will be used to write in the previous buffer

    char buffer_delay[592] = {0}; // ie. : the thd (and last) file's column
    int i2 = 0;

    int flag_column = 0; // 0 = first file's column, 1 = snd one, 2 = last one (precision : two columns are separated by a space)
    // <!-- ### -->

    while(current_char != EOF) {
        current_char = fgetc(file);

        if(current_char != ' ') { // So current_char is : the char to type XOR The number of times XOR The delay XOR \n
            if(current_char == '\n' || current_char == EOF) { // So we just read an entire line of the file : we have valued the var "char_to_print" + the 2 buffers
                pid = fork(); // A new process is created and will do its job
                if(pid != 0) { // So we just read an entire line + we are the parent process , SO : we re-init all the vars and we're going to read the next file's line
                    flag_column = 0;
                    memset(buffer_number_of_prints, 0, 592);
                    i1 = 0;
                    memset(buffer_delay, 0, 592);
                    i2 = 0;
                    continue; // We're going to read the next file's line

                } else { // If the current process is a child, it has to do its job (ie. : printing the typed char with x delay and y times)
                    int i = 0;
                    int max = atoi(buffer_number_of_prints);
                    int del = atoi(buffer_delay); // These two buffers have been filed by the parent process
                    for(i; i < max; i++) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "%c", char_to_print);
                        sleep(del);
                    }
                    return 0; // The process ended its job so we stop it

                }
            }

            // If we are the parent process (the child ones have been stopped previously thanks to the instruction `return 0`), we fill the var `char_to_print` and the two buffers according to the value of the var `flag_column`
            if(flag_column == 0) {
                char_to_print = current_char;
            } else if(flag_column == 1) {
                buffer_number_of_prints[i1] = current_char;
                i1++;
            } else if(flag_column == 2) {
                buffer_delay[i2] = current_char;
                i2++;
            }
        }  else { // If we encounter a space in the reading of the file, it means we are changing of column : so we increment this var
            flag_column++;
        }
    }

    // The parent process close the file's stream
    if(fclose(file) != 0) {
        perror("Close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Before ending, the parent process wait for its children ones
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char current_char` -> `int current_char`! `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` intentionally!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! unfortunately it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Comments are not answers. Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: You want to remove the C++ `#include`s and add the appropriate C headers.

Comment: Also this `for(i;` is useless. Just delete this single `i`.

Comment: To see the characters appear as they get printed flush `stdout` after each print-statement and before the call to `sleep()` by adding a `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Thank you @alk, with fflush it's a bit better. But for example, 'a' appears only 2 times and not 4 times as indicated in the file. Edit : it's clear the parent process ends too quickly. But i wrote a "wait(NULL)" so it shouldn't.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Cannot reproduces this. After applying the minimal adjustments as mentioned above (especially also the one mentioned by *Olaf*), the code works fine here.

Comment: It should not matter when the parent process ends. After it read the whole file and spawned all its children its work is done.

Comment: @stark : i'm using KUbuntu in VirtualBox. VB is run in Windows 10.

Comment: @alk : with this file, it seems to work : 'a 4 2' and 'b 2 7'. But for example with 'a 4 2' and 'b 3 7', only 2 b are wrote.

Comment: Make sure sure input isn't in mult-byte character format. Count the characters and compare the number to the file's size. Add one or two for each newline.

Comment: @alk : the file has a size of 11 bytes. The command 'wc' returns : '1 6 11 file.jobs' (this file contains 'a 4 2' and in the next line : 'b 3 7'). I didn't understand your last sentence ?

Comment: If you are not allocating multiple cores in VirtualBox, then sleep will block everything.  Also not sure what fork does, since this is all running in a single Windows process.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. It's the wait(NULL), which must be replaced by "while(wait(NULL) > 0) {}". Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It's the 'wait(NULL)', which must be replaced by 'while(wait(NULL) > 0) {}'.

So the source becomes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pid_t pid;

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        perror("Open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // <!-- The following vars are used for the reading of the file -->
    char current_char = 0;

    char char_to_print; // ie. : the first file's column

    char buffer_number_of_prints[592] = {0}; // ie. : the snd file's column
    int i1 = 0; // Will be used to write in the previous buffer

    char buffer_delay[592] = {0}; // ie. : the thd (and last) file's column
    int i2 = 0;

    int flag_column = 0; // 0 = first file's column, 1 = snd one, 2 = last one (precision : two columns are separated by a space)
    // <!-- ### -->

    while(current_char != EOF) {
        current_char = (char) fgetc(file);

        if(current_char != ' ') { // So current_char is : the char to type XOR The number of times XOR The delay XOR \n
            if(current_char == '\n' || current_char == EOF) { // So we just read an entire line of the file : we have valued the var "char_to_print" + the 2 buffers
                pid = fork(); // A new process is created and will do its job
                if(pid != 0) { // So we just read an entire line + we are the parent process, SO : we re-init all the vars and we're going to read the next file's line
                    flag_column = 0;
                    memset(buffer_number_of_prints, 0, 592);
                    i1 = 0;
                    memset(buffer_delay, 0, 592);
                    i2 = 0;
                    continue; // We're going to read the next file's line

                } else { // If the current process is a child, it has to do its job (ie. : printing the typed char with x delay and y times)
                    int i = 0;
                    int max = atoi(buffer_number_of_prints);
                    int del = atoi(buffer_delay); // These two buffers have been filed by the parent process
                    for(; i < max; i++) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "%c ", char_to_print);
                        fflush(stdout);

                        if(i < max-1) {
                            sleep(del);
                        }
                    }
                    return 0; // The process ended its job so we stop it

                }
            }

            // If we are the parent process (the child ones have been stopped previously thanks to the instruction `return 0`), we fill the var `char_to_print` and the two buffers according to the value of the var `flag_column`
            if(flag_column == 0) {
                char_to_print = current_char;
            } else if(flag_column == 1) {
                buffer_number_of_prints[i1] = current_char;
                i1++;
            } else if(flag_column == 2) {
                buffer_delay[i2] = current_char;
                i2++;
            }
        }  else { // If we encounter a space in the reading of the file, it means we are changing of column : so we increment this var
            flag_column++;
        }
    }

    // The parent process closes the file's stream
    if(fclose(file) != 0) {
        perror("Close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Before ending, the parent process wait for its children ones
    while(wait(NULL) > 0) { ;; }
    return 0;
}
```